# How to Import a JS file into my JS file without using HTML?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a JS on a webpage which scraps the store site to see if the shoe I want is in stock or not and when it is, it will send me an email to notify that they are in stock. However, I am trying to import a JS script which allows me to send an email to myself to notify me but it uses html, so i was wondering if there is a way around that. And any suggestions for how to send myself an email without using any sort of script which requires html would also be great, thanks.

edit: i want it as a online library

Comment: "how to send myself an email without using html" I have no clue what that means....

Comment: How are you running the screen scraper?

Comment: sorry, fixed the little typo, and I am using violentmonkey to run my js and trying to use script from here https://smtpjs.com/

Comment: If you're using a modern browser, you can just add `import 'https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js'` to the top of your script. Or you can add a require directive: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require